# App works in Xcode but not through TestFlight?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, crash, testflight

I'm having issues with my app crashing after downloading it via TestFlight. When I run it on my device via Xcode, it runs fine, and works 100% as it should.

When I downloaded it via TestFlight to test it before sending to to beta testers, it's opens up and logs in fine, but the second i try to make a post it crashes. It has something to do with the post button, but since it only crashes when using the package sent through TestFlight I have no idea where to start with this one.

Any help appreciated

Comment: But isn't that what the crash report is for? https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Comment: By the way, when you build and run on your device via Xcode, the default is that you use the Debug configuration. But the build for TestFlight is a Release configuration. So it may be that you can get the same crash directly from Xcode by building with a Release configuration. It might not crash, but worth a try.

Comment: Great, thank you Matt! I will look into this now.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just re-uploaded the app to iTunes Connect and downloaded it via TestFlight again on my iPhone and it works fine. Not sure what the issue was.